# How to select the listbox using querystring in c#

Tags: c#

I am using c#.

I am trying to select the listbox values from the data coming in querystring. Below is code.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Security.GetString(Page.Request.Params["VT"])))
        {            
            string[] strCntVisit = Security.GetString(Page.Request.Params["VT"]).Split(',');

            foreach (string i in strCntVisit)
            {
                lstContriesVisited1.SelectedValue = i;

            }                
        }
```

my problem is that the above code is traversing perfectly, however the issue is that in my listbox my last value of (i) is selected not all the values in querystring.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you saying that you want all values selected from the listbox?

Comment: what u reauired? all values or one one value you selected.Pls specify

Comment: All the values that exists in Page.Request.Params["VT"] to be selected in my first list box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ListBox` has its [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property set to `Multiple`, you can do:

```
string vtParam = Security.GetString(Page.Request.Params["VT"]);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vtParam)) {            
    string[] strCntVisit = vtParam.Split(',');
    foreach (string i in strCntVisit) {
        ListItem item = lstContriesVisited1.Items.FindByValue(i);
        if (item != null) {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }                
}
```

**EDIT:** The following should answer your comment:

```
foreach(ListItem item in lstContriesVisited1.Items) {
    lstContriesVisited2.Items.Add(item);
}
lstContriesVisited1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks Hamidi, one more question, now little change in question, what I want now that I will remove all the items from my first lstContriesVisited1 and will add them to lstContriesVisited2 listbox, please what changes I need to do for this.

Answer (score 1):

SelectedValue is a single item only. Assuming you're using an ASP.NET ListControl, try setting the Selected property on items that match your criteria.

```
List<string> validItems = new List<string>(strCntVisit);
foreach (ListItem i in lstContriesVisited1.Items) {
    if (validItems.Contains(i.Text)) {
        i.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string vt = Security.GetString(Page.Request.Params["VT"]);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vt))
{
    string[] valuesToSelect = vt.Split(',');
    foreach (ListItem li in lstContriesVisited1.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = Array.Contains(valuesToSelect, li.Value);
    }
}
```

(If the `VT` parameter could potentially contain a lot of values then it *might* be quicker to change `valuesToSelect` from an array to a `HashSet<T>`.)